# How to write modular CSS as far as pseudo-elements are concerned?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, reusability

Let's say that by design all elements should look like tiles of a given color and with some shadow; something like this:

```css
.panel {
  background-color: #bbffff;
  padding: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0em rgba(0,0,0,50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
Some text
</div>
```

At this point, thinking about writing modular CSS, I'd be already tempted to pick the `box-shadow` declaration and put it in its own ruleset,

```css
.down-right-box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0em rgba(0,0,0,50%);
}
```

so that I can reuse it by adding `class="down-right-box-shadow"` to an HTML tag without bringing in also `background-color` and `padding` declarations.

Now assume that, for some reason, the CSS uses pseudo-elements to create some effects close to those tiles, something like this:

```css
.panel {
  background-color: #bbffff;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}

.down-right-box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0em rgba(0,0,0,50%);
}

.panel::after {
  content: "";
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0em rgba(0,0,0,50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="panel down-right-box-shadow">
Some text
</div>
```

Clearly the intent is that the `::after` pseudo-element has the same shadow as everything else on the page, but since it's a pseudo-element, I can't remove the `box-shadow` declaration from within it in favour of adding `class="down-right-box-shadow"` in the HTML, because there's no element in the HTML for it.

So I have to rewrite the same declaration for `.down-right-box-shadow` at least in these two places.

If tomorrow something in the `.down-right-box-shadow` ruleset changes, I'll have to remember applying the same change to the `.panel::after` ruleset.

Is there any clean way out of this code replication?

Comment: CSS variables ....

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I'd know how to write a variable for the colors and lenghts, but that would still mean I'd have to write `box-shadow: var(--zero-dot-5) var(--zero-dot-5) var(--zero-dot-5) var(--zero) var(--black-50);` in two places, no?

Comment: you make a variable for the whole shadow declaration and then use it whenever you want then all you have to do is to update that variable once

Comment: @TemaniAfif, are you saying that I can do `variable: "box-shadow: bla bla bla;";` and then write `var(--variable);` instead of `box-shadow: bla bla bla;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temani Afif has got a point; using variables:

```css
:root {
  --down-right-box-shadow: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0em rgba(0,0,0,50%);
}
.panel {
  background-color: #bbffff;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}

.down-right-box-shadow {
  box-shadow: var(--down-right-box-shadow);
}

.panel::after {
  content: "";
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: var(--down-right-box-shadow);
}
```

```html
<div class="panel down-right-box-shadow">
    Some text
</div>
```

---

I may be missing something, but this should work as well:

```
.down-right-box-shadow,
.panel.down-right-box-shadow::after {
  box-shadow: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0em rgba(0,0,0,50%);
}
```

Of course you'd have to add multiple selectors in case you want other elements that are not `.panel`, but it solves the multiple `box-shadow` problem

```css
.panel {
  background-color: #bbffff;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}

.down-right-box-shadow,
.panel.down-right-box-shadow::after {
  box-shadow: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0em rgba(0,0,0,50%);
}

.panel::after {
  content: "";
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel down-right-box-shadow">
Some text
</div>
```

Comment: _Enlico has got a point too though_, well actually it was Temani Afif's suggestion :P

Comment: Whoops, must have been up too late again. I edited the answer just for Afif :)